# Neo4j Docker: http-post returns error EOF

Tags: docker, neo4j, http-headers, http-post

I wrote a service which purpose is to archive some sort of data every 10s.
My problem is that after aprox. 3-4 hours the service is no longer capable of writing to the neo4j-docker datatbase.
I'm confident that I am closing the connection the right way. Strangely after restarting the neo4j-docker everything is back to normal, as it supposed to be.
I'm wondering if that is some sort of limitation of the community-version of neo4j, if so it would be really nice to tell me.
Or do I need to modify a parameter of the linux image neo4j is running in, some sort of max. connections setting?

I am providing the followinng params as headers to the post:

```
 {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"  
    "Connection":   "close"
 }
```

After committing the request, I'm closing the connection.

Client Side Error Message:

```
Post "http://192.168.178.55:7474/db/neo4j/tx/commit": EOF
```

Neo4j Errror Log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

2021-02-25 00:44:47.908+0000 WARN /db/neo4j/tx/commit
```

Comment: The first thing I'd do is to look into the Neo4j logs to see if that shows any errors. I've been using community editions since v2 and haven't come across a rate limit so it's likely something else

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2021-02-25 00:41:55.277+0000 WARN /db/neo4j/tx/commit. Shouldn't the garbage collector clear unused memory and make it available again? Anyway how can I configure it the right way?

Comment: Yes but it's probably not clearing down quick enough so you need to look at your memory memory consumption and may need to allocatre more memory to the container. Have a read through https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-memory-consumption/ which may help. You can also have a look https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin-memrec/

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I have set new parameters regarding allocated memory for the docker-container! Will have to see if that resolves the issue. But anyway thank you

Comment: I hope it does :)

Comment: It did! Issue resolved, thank you! If you want to go ahead and answer the Question so I can mark your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's probably not clearing down quick enough so you need to look at your memory memory consumption and may need to allocatre more memory to the container. Have a read through [Understanding Memory Consumption](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-memory-consumption/) within the knowledgebase which may help. You can also have a the [memory recommendations section](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin-memrec/) as well.